# Cross applying or inner joining as subquery for a TVF

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, table-valued-parameters

**Situation:**

I have a `TVF` with one parameter `DATE`. I want to allow the user to input a list of strings as an additional parameter. I am familiar with user types but I don't want to use it.

**Function:** `dbo.fnExample(@StartDate)`

**Here are my two options:**
**Option 1**

```
SELECT base.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnExample('2019-05-01')) AS base
INNER JOIN ( VALUES
('something'),
('something2'),
('n'),
(...)) AS base2(ColumnA)
ON base.ColumnA=base2.ColumnA
```

**Option 2** (not working because im not sure how to join on that column with a `cross apply`).

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES
('something'),
('something2'),
('n'),
(...)) AS base2(ColumnA)
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnExample('2019-05-01')
```

**Objective:**

My question is three-fold. Which would have a better performance? Are there any other options not mentioned above that could be better? What are the limiations from the proposed options ? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `JOIN`, not `APPLY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.fnExample('2019-05-01') f JOIN
     ( VALUES ('something'), ('something2'), ('n'), (...)
     ) AS base2(ColumnA)
     ON  f.columnA = base2.ColumnA;
```

That is, table-valued functions do not have to be called using `APPLY`.  `APPLY` is a way to pass in arguments from other `FROM`-clause entries.

Comment: it performed better than Option 1.